# What is the correct way of overriding render method in Menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, menu, overriding

I did perform investigation and I didn't find good and constructive information to my questions. That is why my question is regarding the control which I would like to extend and render the controls on my own way.I'm working with SharePoint but the SharePoint aspnet control is sealed so I cannot derive from it.

What I have is a menu control which derives from:
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu 
or 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AspMenu
I don't see any big difference. And I have the data source / data provider.

```
SiteMapDataSource dataSource = this.GetDataSource() as SiteMapDataSource;
SiteMapProvider provider = dataSource.Provider;
```

So I have all the needed elements.

Now the base classe has a lot of different methods which I can override, but I'm not sure how to start with.

Where and how should I create controls to render?
Where do I render those controls?
The contols they exist of html?

```
<ul>
 <li> </li>
 ...
</ul>
```

How do I build then a menu based on the provider?

**Just a small update to give a full picture:**
I do this because I need to render first control not as a link and text but as a image link with image set to a provided url.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use extension method on Menu

```
public static void YourExtension(this Menu control)
{
     control.YourPropertyTarget = ....;
}
```

Comment: what do i solve with this? Can I render the first control as a imagelink istead of text link?